# Policy gradient/REINFORCE algorithm with RNN: why does this converge with SGM but not Adam?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, rnn, reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients

I am working on training RNN model on caption generation with REINFORCE algorithm. I adopt self-critic strategy (see paper [Self-critical Sequence Training for Image Captioning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.00563.pdf)) to reduce the variance. I initialize the model with a pre-trained RNN model (a.k.a. warm start). This pre-trained model (trained with log-likelihood objective) got 0.6 F1 score in my task.

When I use adam optimizer to train this policy gradient objective, the performance of my model drops to 0 after a few epochs. However, if I switch to gradientdescent optimizer and keep everything else the same, the performance looks reasonable and slightly better than the pre-trained model. Is there any idea why is that?

I use tensorflow to implement my model.

Comment: maybe you could show the relevant pieces of code otherwise people have to guess what could be wrong :)

Comment: Thank you! I don't think there is any bug in my code, because I tested it so many times with different inputs. I just want to know if in theory there is any idea of why this happened.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code there's not much we can do but, I'd guess you need to significantly lower the learning rate. From my experience Adam requires a significantly lower learning rate compared to SGD.

Comment: I do start from a very small learning rate, but it does not help. I am wondering if adam failed because of its momentum mechanism. In RL sequence training, it is very likely to sample a very bad sequence which has 0 reward and the model get 0 gradient with that sample. However, adam with momentum still updates the model even if the gradient is zero. Would that be a problem?

Comment: @Kechen But that shouldn't make the model diverge, It should only make it learn slower

Comment: so you think the problem is the implementation? Do you have any experience on training RNN with RL objective?